# Standard error and bias zero with bootstrapping

Tags: r, regression, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I want to take my dataset bodyfat_trimmed and use bootstrapping to retrieve the mean and the standard errors. However, I seem to be using the same data all the time and therefore get zero standard error and bias. How can I solve this?

```
bsfunc <- function(data) {
    set.seed(1)
    x <- model.matrix(reduced_BIC_fit)[, -1]
    y <- data$density
    bootdata <- sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)/2)
    x.train <- x[bootdata, ]
    y.train <- y[bootdata]
    bootframe <- data.frame(bodyfat_trimmed[train, ])
    fit <- lm(density ~ age + abdomen + wrist, data = bootframe)
    stats <- coef(summary(fit))[, "Estimate"]
    return(stats)}
strap <- boot(data = bodyfat_trimmed, sim = "parametric", statistic =    bsfunc, R=1000)
strap
```

Output:

```
PARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = bodyfat_trimmed, statistic = bsfunc, R = 1000, sim =  "parametric")


Bootstrap Statistics :
         original  bias    std. error
t1*  1.1360858253       0           0
t2* -0.0000889957       0           0
t3* -0.0018446625       0           0
t4*  0.0050609837       0           0
```

Comment: Your function has `set.seed(1)` in the first line. What happens if you take that out?

Answer (score 1):

If the seed is within the function the sample function will be somewhat repetitive.

```
bsfunc<-function(){set.seed(1); sample(1:10,1)}
bsfunc()
[1] 3
bsfunc()
[1] 3
bsfunc()
[1] 3
```

PS
Your `bsfunc` is also misconceived. As written, `train` (i.e. `bootframe <- data.frame(bodyfat_trimmed[train, ])`) doesn't come from within this function. And normally **the whole point** of `boot` is to do the bootstrap resampling. whilst `bsfunc` should just be a straight statistic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this brings clarity!
So, putting the seed outside and using the bsfunc just for the statistic and fit, I still produce the same result over and over.

    `set.seed(1)
    bsfunc <- function(data) {
        fit <- lm(density ~ age + abdomen + wrist, data = data)
        stats <- coef(summary(fit))[, "Estimate"]
      return(stats)}
  strap <- boot(data = bodyfat_trimmed, sim = "parametric", statistic = bsfunc, R=1000)
  strap`
I don't quite understand how the boot() function samples.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... Did you ever get a fix on this issue?